# Jquery multiselect widget - Single select inside update panel is not working after post back

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, github, jquery-plugins

I am using Eric Hynds multiselect widget on asp.net page. Control is inside update panel.

Single select works fine the first time page is loaded but after post back it is not working. I can't select the different item from the drop down. I have tried in IE9 and FF.

```
<head runat="server">
<title ></title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_theme/jquery.multiselect.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_theme/jquery.multiselect.filter.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.multiselect.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.multiselect.filter.js"></script>

</head>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

    </asp:ScriptManager>
<div>        

       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSearch" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="uc_DDiscipline">
       <asp:ListBox ID="GroupDropDownList2" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="first" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="second" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="third" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
        </div>     
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/inspector-search.js"></script>
    </ContentTemplate> 
           </asp:UpdatePanel>                        


</div>
</form>
```

I have tried with and without SelectionMode="Multiple" but no success.

Here is the script;

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(subscribeClicks);


prm.add_endRequest(function () {

$("#uc_DDiscipline select").multiselect({
    //multiple: true,
    header: "-- View All --",
    multiple: false,
    noneSelectedText: "-- View All --",
    selectedList: 1,
    minWidth: 265
  });

  $('#uc_DDiscipline select').removeClass('ui-multiselect-menu');
  });


function subscribeClicks() {

$("#uc_DDiscipline select").multiselect({
    //multiple: true,
    header: "-- View All --",
    multiple: false,
    noneSelectedText: "-- View All --",
    selectedList: 1,
    minWidth: 265
});
```

}

Comment: If your "post back" rewrites the DOM element, you'll need to reinitialise the widget, too

Comment: i have tried but still not working

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution here http://tiku.io/questions/1502413/jquery-multiselect-widget-not-working-inside-asp-net-updatepanel in case some else is looking for it.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {
$('.ui-multiselect-menu').each(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
$('#uc_DDiscipline select').multiselect({
    header: "-- View All --",
    multiple: false,
    noneSelectedText: "-- View All --",
    selectedList: 1,
    minWidth: 265
});
});


//On Page Load
$(function () {
$("#uc_DDiscipline select").multiselect({
    //multiple: true,
    header: "-- View All --",
    multiple: false,
    noneSelectedText: "-- View All --",
    selectedList: 1,
    minWidth: 265
});
});
```

Ref: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Plugins-not-working-after-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Partial-PostBack-or-when-Asynchronous-request-is-over.aspx

**Cause:**

All jQuery plugins are applied on the Page Load event of the HTML Page or in other words document ready event which is fired when the whole page or document is rendered completely in browser. Now jQuery assigns a unique identification to all controls when applying the plugin. But when some control is inside UpdatePanel and a Partial PostBack occurs the Unique Ids assigned by jQuery is lost and hence the plugin stops working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the PageRequestManager events (page_loaded & endRequest) to call the subscribeClicks method , you can call the method from code behind like this :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"multiFn","subscribeClicks()",true);
```

Put the above code in the page_load method, so that it will be called every time
This should solve your problem. Good luck!